# Laravel - Dispatching a job not working from a repository

Tags: php, laravel, controller, repository, jobs

**when I try to dispatch a job from a controller it works.**

however when I do the same from a repository it gives me an error.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Retailer;

use App\Jobs\SlackJob;
use App\Traits\CreateOrderTrait;

class CreateOrderRepo
{
   use CreateOrderTrait;

   public function create($store_id)
     {
        $slackJob = new SlackJob("Test", 1);
        $slackJob = $slackJob->onQueue('high');
        $this->dispatch($slackJob);
     }
}
```

the error:

> Call to undefined method App\Repositories\Retailer\CreateOrderRepo::dispatch()

Comment: use helper dispatch() function

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have a dispatch() function in `CreateOrderRepo`, so using it in a `$this` context won't work.

Comment: `use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs` trait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the trait to dispatch the jobs:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
```

Comment: how is this different from `app('Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher')->dispatch($job);`? i typically use that 

Comment: It's just lengthier, nothing more. Usually you would like to do `dispatch($job)` or `Job::dispatch()` rather than `app('Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher')->dispatch($job)`

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$this->dispatch($slackJob);
```

to this

```
dispatch($slackJob);
```

Comment: Including the trait works as well as it puts the dispatch method into your class but I always prefer to see less code, especially when it's still very clear what's going on, personal preference though.

Comment: How is `dispatch($job)` less code or less clear than `Job::dispatch()`? I think either way is fine, just personal preference. But I don't see either one being more code or less clear

Comment: If an extra use statement doesn't qualify as "more code" I'm not sure how to help you but thanks for reiterating my point that it's personal preference.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, one whole statement! Wow, so much more code, totally makes sense!

Comment: Glad we could agree, also thank you for noting that your personal preference is different than my personal preference one something that's just personal preference.  I'm not really a fan of superfluous comments either but I guess that's personal preference too.